# TestNG, is there a class level listener like IClassListener like ITestListener

Tags: selenium, testng

I want to perform same action for every class (just like `@BeforeClass`). I guess listeners can do things where you don't have to write code individually, but I did not find in each method/class but can be executed via a listener.  Is there a way to execute my method before every class or just once before method of that class?

Comment: are you looking for @beforeMethod ? This will be executed before each test method in a class

Answer (score 1):

Check the `beforeConfiguration()` method in [TestListenerAdapter](https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master/javadoc/org/testng/TestListenerAdapter.html).

```
@Override
public void beforeConfiguration(ITestResult tr) {
  if(tr.getMethod().getMethodName().equals("methodNameForBeforeClass")) {
    //...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try configuration related methods in [TestListenerAdapter](https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master/javadoc/org/testng/TestListenerAdapter.html):

```
class TestNGListener extends TestListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void beforeConfiguration(ITestResult tr) {
        super.beforeConfiguration(tr);
        logger.info("=========== Configuration method '{}' started ===========", tr.getMethod().getMethodName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationSuccess(ITestResult tr) {
        super.onConfigurationSuccess(tr);
        logger.info("=========== Configuration method '{}' finished ===========", tr.getMethod().getMethodName());
}
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationFailure(ITestResult tr) {
        super.onConfigurationFailure(tr);
        logger.error("!!!!!!!!!!! Configuration method '{}' failed !!!!!!!!!!!", tr.getMethod().getMethodName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Extend `TestListenerAdapter` and override `onTestStart(ITestResult result)` method. This will help you to run something everytime a test starts

Comment: Correct, but i did not ask that. I asked something which acts like my generic @BeforeClass.

Comment: @user2118565 : it is generic. Pls read http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners

Comment: It is generic for methods, suites and and tests. But I did not find that thing for class level. If you think, I missed something, can you please share the code for generic class level listener.